How to configure GCP Spanner ChangeStream read duration in java
We are using GCP spanner changestream in our apache beam java dataflow job. And using SpannerIO connector we are configured it. Code is below,
static class Read extends PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<DataChangeRecord>> {

        @Override
        public PCollection<DataChangeRecord> expand(PBegin input) {
            Pipeline pipeline = input.getPipeline();
            Options options = (Options) pipeline.getOptions();

            // Retrieve and parse the startTimestamp and endTimestamp.
            Timestamp startTimestamp =
                options.getStartTimestamp().isEmpty()
                    ? Timestamp.now()
                    : Timestamp.parseTimestamp(options.getStartTimestamp());
            Timestamp endTimestamp =
                options.getEndTimestamp().isEmpty()
                    ? Timestamp.now()
                    : Timestamp.parseTimestamp(options.getEndTimestamp());

            SpannerConfig spannerConfig =
                SpannerConfig.create()
                    .withProjectId(getSpannerProjectId(options))
                    .withInstanceId(getRequiredData(options.getSpannerInstanceId()))
                    .withDatabaseId(getRequiredData(options.getSpannerDatabase()))
                    .withRpcPriority(options.getSpannerRpcPriority());

            SpannerIO.ReadChangeStream stream =
                SpannerIO.readChangeStream()
                    .withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig)
                    .withMetadataInstance(getRequiredData(options.getSpannerMetadataInstanceId()))
                    .withMetadataDatabase(getRequiredData(options.getSpannerMetadataDatabase()))
                    .withChangeStreamName(options.getSpannerChangeStreamName())
                    .withInclusiveStartAt(startTimestamp)
                    .withInclusiveEndAt(endTimestamp)
                    .withRpcPriority(options.getSpannerRpcPriority());

            String spannerMetadataTableName = options.getSpannerMetadataTableName();
            if (spannerMetadataTableName != null) {
                readChangeStream = readChangeStream.withMetadataTable(spannerMetadataTableName);
            }

            return pipeline.apply("Read from Spanner", stream );
        }

It is working fine. But for every second it is hitting spanner and looking for changes. We have to configure the spanner hit frequency. In log we could see the logs every second after starting the application
INFO: Found 0 to be scheduled (readTimestamp = 2024-06-28T23:30:09.117068001Z)
Jun 28, 2024 7:30:10 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.changestreams.action.DetectNewPartitionsAction getAllPartitionsCreatedAfter
INFO: Found 0 to be scheduled (readTimestamp = 2024-06-28T23:30:09.117068001Z)
Jun 28, 2024 7:30:10 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.changestreams.action.DetectNewPartitionsAction getAllPartitionsCreatedAfter
INFO: Found 0 to be scheduled (readTimestamp = 2024-06-28T23:30:09.117068001Z)
Jun 28, 2024 7:30:10 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.changestreams.action.DetectNewPartitionsAction getAllPartitionsCreatedAfter
INFO: Found 0 to be scheduled (readTimestamp = 2024-06-28T23:30:09.117068001Z)

Can anyone know how to configure this. We don't want to use spanner database client. Is there any way in spannerIO?
Thanks in Advance :)

what you are seeing is the connector checking for new change data partitions, not reading actual changes from Spanner: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner/changestreams/dao/PartitionMetadataDao.java#L198
This is being scheduled every 100ms here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner/changestreams/action/DetectNewPartitionsAction.java#L167

If you cannot write an answer according to [answer] without asking questions beforehand please use your commenting privilege for them.

Is there any way to increase the scheduled duration ? we want to increase the time. How can i do it?
